# SQLite db browser does not show tables

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite-browser

I am creating add contact android application. I am using SQLite database. The app is running perfectly without any error. But DB browser for SQLite does not show the tables created in my database.

I have deleted the database and increased version of the database also.

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name=et_name.getText().toString();
            String number=et_number.getText().toString();


            if(name.trim().length()>0 && number.trim().length()>0){
                Contact contact=new Contact(name,number);
                dbHandler.addContact(contact);
                startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("please fill all the fields").setNegativeButton("ok",null).show();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you extract the database from the emulator/device?

Comment: yes, I used "save as" to extract the database @forpas

Comment: *The app is running perfectly* this means that you can see in your app the data that you insert, right?